# How to get same resolution with 2 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I bought second 22 inch monitor yesterday.
One is benq G2225HD and another is G2255. My problem is that after connecting second monitor I can't get his resolution 1920x1080 as the first ones even manufacturer says it's max resolutions is: 1920x1080 but in windows screen properties it gives me max of 1600x1200 and this doesn't look good. My vga is ATI Radeon HD 4800 series, what could be the problems of not able to reach same resolution on both displays?

E: For first monitor in contrtol panel in display field it says normal display name and for second one only generic monitor, maybe this will help you out too:
[image]

I am using windows 8 RTM version.

Comment: How is that monitor connected?

Comment: Install the correct driver (or updated driver) for your 2nd monitor at Benq's website. The problem is most likelyy the "Generic monitor" setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the g2255 as "generic non-pnp monitor." This means that your computer does not know what the monitor's capabilities are.

One way to fix this is to use a CD that came with the monitor. The manual should tell you what steps to take: ( http://benq.eu/products/LCD/?product=1329&page=downloads&dType=M )